# What options exist to take care of minor children when out of boarding schools?

Tags: usa, us-citizens, legal, children

Assuming, we reside out of US and our child is a US citizen by birth. We wish to send our child to US boarding school at age of 16 for 11th and 12th grade. Then we wish our child pursues undergraduate and graduate studies in the US

Boarding school provides all requirements for minors such as food / laundry etc. However our child graduates from boarding school a few months before turning 18.

Here is our issue

- We don't know any one in the US who can act as guardian or even a
  temporary guardian.
- Our child cannot travel to India since India country
  does not grant visa to children if parents do not attend visa
  interview. Thus child has to wait till child turns 18 years old.

What can we do for a few months (3 months) when child has graduated out of boarding school but not yet turned 18 ?

- Are there any professional temporary guardianship services that we can pay for temporary care ?
- Can we pay the boarding school to remain in the form for 3 months past graduation ?
- Is foster care the only option ? How would it work ?

Comment: how is your child not a citizen of your home country?  Citizens of a country are always allowed back into the country as long as the citizen can prove it

Comment: Is a hotel or rented accommodation (eg AirBnb) an option for three months? What is the minor’s immigration status in the country where you reside?

Comment: Why would your child need a visa to return to her home country? If she does require a visa, why can you — as residents of that home country — not attend the home country visa interview?

Comment: @MatthewBarclay, It depends on the laws of the country in question. For some, if the child acquires citizenship of another country, even by birth to a parent of that nationality, they immediately lose citizenship of the citizen parent's home country. India is a noted example.

Comment: @ouflak: Having another citizenship at birth doesn't conflict with the child having Indian citizenship by descent, at least until age 18.5. However, in order for the child to be an Indian citizen by descent, they would have to be registered at an Indian consulate within one year of birth with the declaration that they do not have a foreign passport, which may not have happened in this case. Also, even if registered as an Indian citizen, if they later get a foreign passport, that could allow the Indian government to revoke the child's citizenship.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica the child's home country is the United States (under Indian law, a child born to Indian parents in the US who has a US passport issued loses Indian citizenship; I assume that the child has a US passport).  The interview would take place in the United States.  The parents are not in the United States.

Comment: Do the boarding schools really assume legal guardianship? ( I went to boarding school, and this one certainly didn't). 
If the problem is that someone needs to "look after" your child, well, if they are almost 18 they ought to be able to look after themselves. Give them a backpack and some pocket money and tell them to have some fun in Europe before college starts.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for your comment. I assumed from the original question that the child was presently in India, along with the child's parents, and thus the OP's wording "...wish to _send_ our child to US boarding school..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the family is making such a serious effort to provide the minor with a good education, I presume the minor will be going on to university. One approach is to wait until the minor has been admitted to a university, and then contact the guidance office of the university for housing options near the university. Private landlords near the university will have experience with students who need housing for a few months, and with students who are minors.

Another option is to seek summer jobs or internships related to the student's intended field of study. Companies or organizations who are in the habit of providing such jobs/internships may be able to advise about housing.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can we hire a private nanny ? Can we hire a temporary guardian ? Is it necessary to enter foster care if none of the options listed above work out ? Appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: University-age minors routinely travel about the country and stay away from home for the summer with no close-at-hand adult supervision. As long as they don't do something to bring themselves to the attention of the authorities, nothing happens. You could contact a lawyer in the appropriate state and issue a power of attorney, which may let the lawyer sign documents related to the child on your behalf.